# cakephp2.0 select

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm new in Cakephp 2.0, but I want to make a view of two tables. I have the following tables:

**hpsas with records: ciname, location, status

ldaps with records: ciname, status**

The query I want to use is:

`select hpsas.ciname, hpsas.status, ldaps.ciname, ldaps.status from cmdb.hpsas, cmdb.ldaps where hpsas.ciname = ldaps.ciname;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting a query that works, or are you wondering how to model your data?

Does you query work now? It looks like one of the fields in your `SELECT` statement (ciname) is redundant since you are joining on it.

Why not:

```
SELECT hpsas.ciname AS ciname, hpsas.status AS hstatus, ldaps.status as lstatus 
FROM cmdb.hpsas, cmdb.ldaps 
WHERE hpsas.ciname = ldaps.ciname;
```

so that you would get something like:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| ciname | hstatus | lstatus        |
+-----------------------------------+
| [data] | [data]  | [data]         |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hoi Johnny, thnx for your reply. I was wondering how to model my data in Cakephp 2.0.